# KETTLE having not output

Tags: java, kettle

I run a kettle.bat,but having not output

kettle.bat

```
cd /d E:\pdi-ce-9.2.0.0-290\data-integration
pan /file=E:\ETL\Hello World.ktr /level=Detailed /logfile=E:\1.log0
```

How can I slove the log error

```
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Error setting output step for Build Model
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : java.lang.NullPointerException
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at org.pentaho.di.core.refinery.extension.DataRefineryTransFinishListener.callExtensionPoint(DataRefineryTransFinishListener.java:57)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at org.pentaho.di.core.extension.ExtensionPointMap.callExtensionPoint(ExtensionPointMap.java:151)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at org.pentaho.di.core.extension.ExtensionPointHandler.callExtensionPoint(ExtensionPointHandler.java:45)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at org.pentaho.di.pan.PanCommandExecutor.exitWithStatus(PanCommandExecutor.java:284)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at org.pentaho.di.pan.PanCommandExecutor.execute(PanCommandExecutor.java:160)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at org.pentaho.di.pan.Pan.main(Pan.java:274)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan -     at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Error processing data providers for annotations.
2022/05/02 11:17:33 - Pan - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: What is your java version? Kettle works with java 8.

Comment: My java version is jdk1.8.0_331,it's work with Kettle. Now i find the ansewer,because the ktr filename contain the space